# Both login/signup button are the same. How do i Give 2 functionalities to the same button.?

Tags: javascript, php, html

my English is not very good so forgive me. I have this login/sign up form on my site. However both login/sign up button are the same only the text changes via onclick. I am able to sign up a user then submit the information within the database. Although, I cannot seem to login a user. I do not know how to make my login as a button and submit, in order to check the for the user within the database. How can I name my button both submit and login??

Page where user tries to login/register:

```
        <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        include_once("php/config/database.php");
        $Email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
        $Password = strip_tags($_POST['Password']);

        $Email = stripslashes($Email);
        $Password = stripslashes($Password);

        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $Email);
        $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $Password);

        $Password = md5($Password);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$Email' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $id = $row['UserID'];
        $db_Password = $row['Password'];

        if($Password == $db_Password) {
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $id;
            header("Location: account.php");
        } else {
            echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
        }

    } ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html >   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>background</title>




        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    </head>

  <body>


    <div class="container demo-1">





      <div class="content">

        <div id="large-header" class="large-header">

      <form  action="signup_destination.php" method="POST" />  
          <div class="box">


      <h1 id="logintoregister">Login</h1>


  <div class="group show">      
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="FirstName" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>First Name</label>
      </div>
    <div class="group show">      
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="Surname" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Surname</label>
      </div>


     <div class="group ">      
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="email" name="Email" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
      </div>

    <div class="group">      
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="password" id="password" name="Password" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Password</label>
      </div>
    <div class="group show">      
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="password"  id="confirm_password" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      </div>



    <button id="buttonlogintoregister"  type = "submit" name="submit">Login</button>

      <p id="plogintoregister">By registering, You accept all terms and conditons </p>
      <p id="textchange" onclick="register()"> Sign Up</p>



             </form> 

      <!-- Related demos -->

      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>


</body> </html>


Javascript:


var cont = 0;

function register(){

     cont++;
                if(cont==1){
            $('.box').animate({height:'600px'}, 550); 
            $('.show').css('display','block');          
            $('#logintoregister').text('Register');             
            $('#buttonlogintoregister').text('Register');           
            $('#plogintoregister').text("Sei gia' registrato?");            
            $('#textchange').text('Login');         }       else                        {           
            $('.show').css('display','none');           
            $('.box').animate({height:'365px'}, 550);           
            $('#logintoregister').text('Login');                            
            $('#buttonlogintoregister').text('Login');          
            $('#plogintoregister').text("Non sei iscritto?");           
            $('#textchange').text('Register');          cont = 0;                       } }

var password = document.getElementById("password")   , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword(){   if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");   } else {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');   } }

password.onchange = validatePassword; confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

Comment: Reading through your code only to get to the jQuery part which I'm not familiar with, please specify that you use jQuery with the tags :) What I can help you with though is your password hashing; md5 is broken and should not be used to hash passwords, there are several public decrypters for it. Use sha512 (php: hash("sha512",$password)) instead, and repeat it atleast 50000 (51505 for example) times (Hash the hashed password) to prevent 'rainbow tables' from being easily constructed. Additionally to prevent users with the same password to get the same hashed password you can use salt.

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

You can send an AJAX-request against your DB checking if the email exists, when the user leaves the inputfield for email.

If it doesn't exists, you can replace the "Login"-Text with "Sign up".

Give your email input an id="email" and then

```
$( "#email" ).blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: // Add script that checks for existing email, should return count
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        if (returned count = 0) {
            $("#buttonlogintoregister").html("Sign up");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i think that is not an optimized choice , rather I would choose onClick